# How to obtain Felix Framework's properties in the config.properties file?

Tags: java, properties, osgi, apache-felix, osgi-bundle

I have this line of code that returns me null and it should return 9193 which is the value that the property really has in my config.properties file...

```
System.getProperty("org.osgi.service.http.port") // returns null dunno why
```

My config.properties has the property correctly set up:

```
org.osgi.service.http.port=9193
```

Probably I am missing something here, because it is the first time I try to access those properties. I've googled a lot, so there is lack of examples online or I didn't search for the correct keywords.

What should I add/change to that line to make it return the correct value?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use [BundleContext.getProperty](http://www.osgi.org/javadoc/r4v43/core/org/osgi/framework/BundleContext.html#getProperty%28java.lang.String%29). The config.properties are set as OSGi framework properties. So this should be a way to retrieve them.

Comment: Works! So the resulting code is:

@Override
 public void start(BundleContext context) throws Exception {
final String port = context.getProperty("org.osgi.service.http.port");
 }

Thanks!